# Unity 2D - How to make a movement point system in a map based on non-gridded tiles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, for-loop, foreach, 2d

I'm making a wargame set on a map in which the player's divisions move across irregular-shaped provinces (a la Paradox) in a turn-based manner. I want to make it so that each turn, the divisions can move an amount of provinces equal to the division's movement points (by default 2).

I'm having trouble (mainly because im a newbie) coding a way for the game to detect which provinces are in range to a division, aside from the ones directly adjacent to the division's current position. Whatever I do, the game either detects all provinces as "in-range" or just doesn't make an accurate calculation.

The provinces are not in a grid system because of their irregular shapes, so I'm using collider overlaps to detect which ones are next to each other. Feel free to tell me if there's a better way to do it.

Here's what I tried (skip to GetTilesInRange):

```
{ 
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        Army = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Division");   
        Map = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tile");
        DivisionHeightOffset = new Vector3(0f, -ñDivisionHeightOffsetY, 0f);
        
        
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
       mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
       CheckforSelectedDivisions();       
    }


    private void CheckforSelectedDivisions()    
    {             
      foreach ( GameObject Division in Army)
      {          
        if (Division.GetComponent<DivisionBehaviour>().Selected && !Checked) 
        {                       
          Checked = true;
          SelectedDivision = Division;
          SelectedDivisionPosition = Division.transform.position;
          NameOfSelectedDivision = Division.name;
          DivisionOverlapPoint = Division.transform.position + DivisionHeightOffset; 
          
          DivisionMovementPoints = (Division.GetComponent<DivisionBehaviour>().MovementPoints);
          GetCurrentTile();                                     
        }          
      }
      if(SelectedDivision != null) { if(!SelectedDivision.GetComponent<DivisionBehaviour>().Selected) {Checked = false;}}
    }

    private void GetCurrentTile()
    {
        
        foreach (GameObject Tile in Map) if (Tile.GetComponent<Collider2D>())
        {           
           if(Tile.GetComponent<Collider2D>().OverlapPoint(DivisionOverlapPoint))
           {              
              CurrentTile = Tile;              
              Debug.Log(NameOfSelectedDivision + " is in " + CurrentTile.name);
              CurrentTilePosition = Tile.transform.position;
              CurrentTileBounds = Tile.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds;
              GetTilesInRange();
           }      
        }
    }

  **  private void GetTilesInRange()
    {                                       
       i = DivisionMovementPoints;

        
        foreach (GameObject TileB in Map) if (TileB.GetComponent<Collider2D>() && TileB != CurrentTile && !TileB.GetComponent<TileInfo>().Movable && !TileB.GetComponent<TileInfo>().Movable2)
        {
        
             
             if(TileB.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.Intersects(CurrentTileBounds))
             {
                  
               MovableTile = TileB;
               Debug.Log(MovableTile.name + " is in range!");

                    
                            
             }**

             else if(i > 0 && TileB.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.Intersects(MovableTile.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds))
             {
                  
                    i = i - 1;
                  MovableTile = TileB;
                  Debug.Log(MovableTile.name + " is in range!");
             }

        }


       
    }

    

    
      
    
    





}
```

Comment: What I might suggest instead of relying on collider overlaps to determine adjacent provinces is to have a data structure that represents the provinces on your map, and what neighbours are adjacent to each of them. So each province might be represented by a name, position, traversal cost and a list of neighbour provinces. At that point, you can determine all provinces within a given range of another province by doing a graph-traversal algorithm like a [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: @Serlite I kinda wanted to make a system that would automatically know which provinces have which neighbors, but I guess I'm still not experienced enough for that. It's not necessary at all though so it's all good. Thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have navigation info outside of graphical info. You will probably need to store other data on provinces as well, like production, who owns etc.

```
public class Province    // Class to hold province data
{
    public int ProvinceID;                          // Pointer to Building Type
    public string Name;                              // Name of Province          
    public string Spritename;                     // Sprite to show capital building
    public int BuildingFlags;                      // Flags for the Province
    public List<int> AdjacentProvinces;     // List of adjacent Province IDs 
    public GameObject GO;                       // Game Object Province sprite

}
```

You can search each province for neighbors going through the list of its public List AdjacentProvinces;

You could write a function to return a list of adjacent neighbors.

You could then call this function of each of its adjacent neighobors for each 1 movement step you want to add to see if an Province ID is in range